# grid.py not giving output

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, libsvm, pattern-recognition

I am using `LibSVM` and I used `GRID.py` for `SVM`.  But the problem is I ran it `grid.py` more than hour but it's not giving any output. The error message it gives as follows

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grid.py", line 266, in run
    if rate is None: raise RuntimeError('get no rate')
RuntimeError: get no rate
worker local quit.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Can anybody tell me what's problem? And what is this "worker local quit"?
If anybody want to know more information about implementation or `GRID.py` please feel free to ask. I am having more than `9000` rows with 8 different columns as dataset

Comment: Can you please add the line you wrote to run grid.py?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `GRID.py` with either the parameter *-log2c* or *-log2g*?

It seems that the problem arises when [`LocalWorker.run_one`](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/8f3d96edce6e9363ad40cefe6e135650a10e53fb/tools/grid.py#L290-L295) returns `None`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Github links have a bad habit of getting out of date (any commit that changes the line number will cause issues): if you're going to link to github, use a [permanent link](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/) and include some information about what you're trying to link to. I've edited your answer already for you.